# How to calculate the power of my quantile regression model?

Tags: r, statistical-power, quantile-regression

I have a `quantile regression model` that I fit with the `rq()` function in the `quantreg` package in R.

However, since my sample size if fairly small (n = 36) compared to  the number of X variables (= 8), I need to estimate power for the various regression coefficients. How can I do that?

It would be great to be pointed to a function in R that can do that for a `quantreg model`, but a general explanation of how to calculate power in such a model would be fine as well (I can then code that in R myself).

How can I determine the power for a given `quantile regression model` with a given dataset?

Comment: Simulation is the way

Comment: You shouldn't really calculate power *post-hoc*. That's because the point estimate of the study is within a range of the "truth" ($\pm$ some variability), and the upper limit of the 95% CI will almost always tell you your study is adequately powered while the lower limit will almost always not. However +1 because there's a lot of curiosity on the power of quantile regression.

Comment: I've seen some work of an earnest MS student on the topic. They authored an R package (not on CRAN) here https://rdrr.io/github/tnt198785/rqsamplesize/

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't know what you say clearly. If you want to compare different rq model with different variable that which is better, [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) and [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion)
are common ways, no matter what your regression model is.

In R:

```
fit1 <- rq(...)
fit2 <- rq(...)
AIC(fit1)
AIC(fit2)

BIC(fit1)
BIC(fit2)

## briefly
AIC(fit1, fit2)
BIC(fit1, fit2)
```

And if you want to check which variable is more important to effect the results(feature selection), I have no idea about so.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your effort. What I am after is a way to approximate the probability of detecting a "true" effect when it exists, given my dataset and the set of X's in my quantile regression model. So, with the specific data that I am working with (and its limited size) and some choice of variables in the quantile regression, what would be the power to find a true effect for a coefficient, if it exists?